# Getting a 500 error when I run this sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, coldfusion

It's really weird it works within a one day date range but past that I get a 500 server error. The query runs fine in management studio though.

```
SELECT tblCAPMessages.*, tblCADSNotes.Notes 
FROM tblCAPMessages 
  LEFT JOIN tblCADSNotes ON tblCAPMessages.Identifier = tblCADSNotes.Identifier 
WHERE tblCAPMessages.MsgSent BETWEEN {ts '2013-04-23 10:15:00'} AND {ts '2013-04-23 11:15:59'} 
ORDER BY MsgSent, tblCAPMessages.Identifier
```

Here is the cold fusion code, this is all legacy code. I inherited this system a while back and don't know everything about it yet. I was told that the page worked about a month ago but I don't see any evidence of it.

```
<CFQUERY NAME="GetIncidents" DATASOURCE="#CADS_Datasource#" CachedWithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0,1,0,0)#">
    SELECT  #CADS_Table#.*, tblCADSNotes.Notes  
    FROM    #CADS_Table# LEFT JOIN tblCADSNotes ON #CADS_Table#.Identifier = tblCADSNotes.Identifier
    WHERE   
            #CADS_Table#.MsgSent BETWEEN #Stdate# AND #Enddate# 
            <CFIF IsDefined("attributes.IncidentID")>
                AND #CADS_Table#.IncidentID = #attributes.IncidentID# 
            </CFIF>

            <CFIF IsDefined("attributes.ReportCriteria")>
                <CFLOOP LIST="#attributes.ReportCriteria#" INDEX="criteria">
                    AND #CADS_Table#.#criteria# = '#evaluate( "attributes." & criteria )#'
                </CFLOOP>
            </CFIF>

            <CFIF IsDefined("attributes.Group")>
                    AND #CADS_Table#.DispatchGroup ='#TRIM(attributes.DispatchGroup)#'
            </CFIF>

            <CFIF IsDefined("attributes.ID")>
                    AND #CADS_Table#.Identifier >='DIV#TRIM(attributes.Identifier)#'
            </CFIF>

            <CFIF IsDefined("attributes.Division")>
                AND ( (0=1)
                <CFLOOP LIST="#attributes.Division#" INDEX="criteria">
                    OR (#CADS_Table#.Division = '#criteria#')
                </CFLOOP>
                )
            </CFIF>
    ORDER BY MsgSent, #CADS_Table#.Identifier   
</CFQUERY>


<TABLE Width="100%">
    <TR>
        <TD Align="CENTER">
            <FONT Color="red"><H3>Complete CADS Event Report</H3></FONT>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>

    <TABLE Align="Center" Border="1">
    <TR bgcolor="Silver">
        <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">MsgSent</TH>
        <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">Identifier</TH>
        <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">MsgType</TH>
        <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">TenCode</TH>
        <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">Severity</TH>
        <!--- <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">Certainty</TH> --->
        <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">Status</TH>
        <!--- <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">Division</TH> --->
        <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">DispatchGroup</TH>
        <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">DutyPost</TH>
        <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">Change</TH>
        <TH CLASS="ReportHeaderCell">CountyCode</TH>
    </TR>
    <CFIF GetIncidents.RecordCount NEQ 0>
        <CFOUTPUT QUERY="GetIncidents">
            <TR>
                <TD Align="center">#DateFormat(MsgSent,"mm/dd/yyyy")#<BR>#TimeFormat(MsgSent,"h:mmtt")#</TD>
                <TD Align="center"><FONT Color="Blue">#TRIM(Identifier)#</FONT></TD>
                <TD Align="center">
                    <CFIF TRIM(MsgType) EQ "Alert">
                        <FONT Color="Red"><B>#TRIM(MsgType)#</B></FONT>
                    <CFELSEIF TRIM(MsgType) EQ "CANCEL">
                        <FONT Color="Green"><B>#TRIM(MsgType)#</B></FONT>
                    <CFELSE>
                        <B>#TRIM(MsgType)#</B>
                    </CFIF>
                </TD>
                <TD Align="center">#TRIM(TenCode)#</TD>
                <TD Align="center">#TRIM(SeverityType)#</TD>
                <!--- <TD>#TRIM(Certainty)#</TD> --->
                <TD Align="center">
                    <CFIF TRIM(CADStatus) EQ "Waiting">
                        <FONT Color="Red"><B>#TRIM(CADStatus)#</B></FONT>
                    <CFELSEIF TRIM(CADStatus) EQ "Cleared">
                        <FONT Color="Green"><B>#TRIM(CADStatus)#</B></FONT>
                    <CFELSEIF TRIM(CADStatus) EQ "">
                        &nbsp;
                    <CFELSE>
                        <B>#TRIM(CADStatus)#</B>
                    </CFIF>
                </TD>
                <!--- <TD>#TRIM(Division)#</TD> --->
                <TD Align="center">#TRIM(DispatchGroup)#</TD>
                <TD Align="center">
                    <CFIF TRIM(DutyPost) EQ "">
                        &nbsp;
                    <CFELSE>
                        #TRIM(DutyPost)#
                    </CFIF>
                </TD>
                <TD Align="center">
                    <CFIF TRIM(ChangeAudit) EQ "">
                        &nbsp;
                    <CFELSE>
                        #TRIM(ChangeAudit)#
                    </CFIF>
                <TD Align="center">
                    <CFIF TRIM(Jurisdiction) EQ "">
                        &nbsp;
                    <CFELSE>
                        #TRIM(Jurisdiction)#
                    </CFIF>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD ColSPAN="12">
                    <B>HEADLINE:</B> #TRIM(Headline)#<BR>
                    <B>DESCRIPTION:</B> #TRIM(AreaDescription)#<BR>
                    <B>NOTE:</B> #TRIM(Note)#                   
                    <CFIF Notes NEQ "">
                        <CFSET NotesReplaced = Trim(Replace( Notes, "&##39", "","ALL" ))>
                        <CFSET NotesReplaced = Replace( NotesReplaced, """", "","ALL" )>
                        <CFSET NotesReplaced = Replace( NotesReplaced, CrLf, "<BR>","ALL" )>                    
                        <BR>Dispatcher Notes:  #NotesReplaced#
                    </CFIF>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD ColSPAN="12" bgcolor="##0033FF">&nbsp;</TD>
            </TR>
        </CFOUTPUT>
    <CFELSE>
        <TR>
            <TD ColSPAN="12" Align="Center">No CADS messages found!</TD>
        </TR>
    </CFIF> 
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message and the code you are using to execute the query.

Comment: Also post how many records it returns in management studio please.

Comment: have you altered the table structure? With a `SELECT *` I've ran into issues using `SELECT *` after I've changed the data

Comment: 86 rows, this isn't one that has time out though. I just got one to time out and it had 5,299 rows.

Comment: Yeah I've tried selecting the columns names, less columns also the whole thing works fine if I use a right inner join.

Comment: if you're getting a timeout then that's a completely separate issue

Comment: I don't think it's timing out I told cold fusion to keep loading the pages no matter how long it takes.

Comment: @Guyver, please post the error message you are receiving.

Comment: The website cannot display the page HTTP 500

Comment: What does the exception log say?

Comment: What happens if you hard code the tablename instead of using a variable?

Comment: On your ColdFusion server, look in the `cfusion-out.log` file. It will contain the actual error(s).  Please post it here.

Comment: Also fyi, if ypu are getting 500 server errors instead of the cferrors all the time, this is because you have error output disabled in Iis.
Enable detailed error output and ypu will see the actual.cf errot which is occurring. Hth

Answer (score 0):

So turns out it wasn't a code or database issue. I went into Coldfusion admin and changed this Maximum JVM Heap Size (MB) it was set to 512, doubled it and everything works fine now.

Comment: SO has a stupid 48 hour limit before it's possible to accept your own answer.